# Swift's analog for Java's Runnable

Tags: ios, swift

Surprisingly, Google search returned me nothing about that. 
What I do on Android :

```
void doSomethng(Runnable r){
r.run();
}
```

Which is simply passing some block of code in a context of a sending class and then execute this block by demand. 
How can I do the same with Swift for iOS?

Comment: USe Swift closure with GCD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for function that gets a block without parameters and does not have a return value is following:

```
func doSomethng(runnable: () -> ()){
   runnable()
}
```

If you are going to use such blocks widely you could define a special type for it:

```
typealias Runnable = () -> ()

func doSomethng2(runnable: Runnable){
    runnable()
}
```

I also suggest you to check this site [fuckingclosuresyntax.com](http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/) to quickly get the idea of block/closure's syntax in Swift.

If you need to run blocks in a separate thread check [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with closures:

```
func doSomethng(r: () -> ()) {
    r()
}
```